# UILocalNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber doesn't work in iOS 5 !!!

Tags: uilocalnotification, iso, application-icon

I just moved to iOS 5 and found that UILocalNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber  stopped to work.

When we create any localnotification , we can set applicationIconBadgeNumber. So when pop-up comes up we can see that badgenumber on application icon.

It works fine in iOS 4.X...but in iOS 5 i can not see any icon badge.

Any solution ??

Answer (score 0):

actually, the applicationIconBadgeNumber is still working, the user just has to have the "Badge App Icon" switch on in the 'Notifications' part of 'Settings'.